# On the parity of $a^{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Depending on the parity of the positive integers $a$ and $b$ determine whether $a^{b}$ is even or odd. I cannot find a general law for this.

Comment: What property do all even numbers have?

Comment: What can you say if $a$ is even? Odd?

Comment: @JihoonKang: $2$ devide all of them

Comment: Did you at least try a few test cases?

Comment: @EthanBolker: If $a$ is even then $a^{b}$ is also even

Comment: And if $a$ is odd?

Comment: "$2$ devide all of them"... and $1$ to rule them all.

Answer (score 5):

If $a$ is even, then no matter how many $b$ times you multiply $a$, $a$ will always be even as an even number multiplied by an even number is always even.

Proof: An even number is a number of the form $2k$, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Given two even numbers $p=2m$ and $r=2n$, $$\begin{align}p\times r&= 2m\times 2n \\ &=4mn \\ &=2\times 2mn\end{align}$$ which is of the form $2k$ and is therefore even.

---

If $a$ is odd, then no matter how many $b$ times you multiply $a$, $a$ will always be odd as an odd number multiplied by an odd number is always odd.

Proof: An odd number is a number of the form $2k+1$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Given two odd numbers $p=2m+1$ and $r=2n+1$, $$\begin{align} p \times r &= (2m+1)(2n+1) \\ &= 4mn + 2m + 2n + 1 \\&= 2(2mn + n + m) + 1\end{align}$$ which is of the form $2k+1$ and is therefore odd.